# Serialize large object as JSON and stream it to a varbinary SQL Server column

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, system.text.json

I want to serialize a large object to JSON and store it in a varbinary SQL Server column. Ideally this serialization process would write to the database in chunks directly(streaming).

I wrote the following proof of concept code:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

var random = new Random();

var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 125_000_000; i++)
    sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(random.NextInt64(26) + 97));
var sbAsString = sb.ToString();

Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

SqlConnection sqlConnection = new("Server=localhost;Database=serializationtest;Trusted_Connection=True");
sqlConnection.Open();

using SqlCommand sqlCommand = new("insert into test (value) values (@value)", sqlConnection);

var valueStream = new MemoryStream();
JsonSerializer.Serialize(valueStream, sbAsString);
valueStream.Position = 0;

SqlParameter parameter = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Binary, -1);
parameter.Value = valueStream;

sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

Console.WriteLine("Just for debugger");
```

Obviously this temporarily stores the serialized data in memory, and thus the memory graph looks like:

[image: memory usage over time]

Where the first increase is caused by the string creation, and the second increase is caused by the `JsonSerializer.Serialize` to the memory stream.

Is it possible to do something like `JsonSerializer.Serialize(BUFFERED_STREAM_TO_DB)` which would directly write to the database, and thus (reduce) the second increase in memory?

Comment: I'm no expert but according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support there should be some sort of support for streaming data, if your serializer supports it. Scroll a bit down for example with a File

Comment: JSON is text. Why varbinary?

Comment: SQL Server has JSON functions. These can't be used with opaque BLOBs. Besides, if the JSON is so large, it's probably a bad idea to store it in the database